# Parser errors not shown in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

recently, I'm working on the asp.net c# framework, I had a problem with the insert query but I can't see the parser error it shows a blank page. That's why I can't figure out the problem with my code.
here it's my code and my web.config file.

web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <system.web>

      <compilation  targetFramework="4.7.2" />
      <!-- ******************** -->
      
  </system.web>

  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler extension=".cs" language="c#;cs;csharp" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7.3 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <compiler extension=".vb" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

the code of insert query:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO [transaction] (employeeName, receivedDate, recipient, senderParty, receivedParty, tranNum, email, status, userID)" +
             "values (@employName, @recDate, @recipientName, @sendName, @recName, @tranNumber, @employEmail, @stat, @id)";
            //Response.Write(reciveDate.Value);
            //Response.Write(empEmail);

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employName", employeeName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recDate", reciveDate.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recipientName", reciever.Value); ;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sendName", senderAdress.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recName", recieverAdress.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tranNumber", Convert.ToInt32(tranID.Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employEmail", empEmail);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", "p");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", empID);
                a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

I tried to insert data into the Microsoft SQL Management server, but it didn't work and I can't see the parser error.

How I can display the parser error?

please help me,
thanks

Comment: just an observation. How does SQL respond when there is no space between userID) and values (@employName?
i.e. when you do the string + string over two lines you don't add any space. Not sure if this is related. even if it is related then it doesn't help you debug. perhaps if it's a sql error then you can locate something through a trace / profiler.

Comment: are you getting an `SqlException` thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put try catch and see the exception.

you also need to first run your query directly in the SQL server and see if there is anything wrong with your query.

and I am not sure but your query is incorrect here. it is producing the below query.

```
INSERT INTO [transaction] (employeeName, receivedDate, recipient, senderParty, receivedParty, tranNum, email, status, userID)values (@employName, @recDate, @recipientName, @sendName, @recName, @tranNumber, @employEmail, @stat, @id)
```

if you look it carefully there is no space before values. so you need to correct it.

and please declare con with `using` statement.

Also please avoid `AddWithValue` instead use `Parameters.Add`

Answer (score 0):

as noted, you should have a space before "values".

or use @ for the string, and use a line break.

And you should STRONG type the parameters.

(don't use addwith)

Thus:

```
sql = @"INSERT INTO [transaction] 
(employeeName, receivedDate, recipient, senderParty, receivedParty, tranNum, email, status, userID)
VALUES (@employName, @recDate, @recipientName, @sendName, @recName, @tranNumber, @employEmail, @stat, @id)";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@employName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = employeeName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@recDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = reciveDate.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@recipientName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = reciever.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sendName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = senderAdress.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@recName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = recieverAdress.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tranNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(tranID.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@employEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = empEmail;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@stat", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "p";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empID;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And where are the variables coming from?

If those are text boxes, then you are to use MyAddress.Text, and not MyAddress.Value

## Edit: showing errors in the application

add to system.web this:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" >        
</customErrors>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I will try it but is there no way to see the parser error? because I really need to know.

Comment: Well your information suggests this is a code error and not likely a compilation error. So that points to say null values or perhaps the data don't exist. Also are you sure the values have data?

Comment: yes, I tried your suggestion and it works! But what I mean is that the parser error page does not appear, it just shows a blank page... But I think I can handle it with a try-catch.

Comment: Well, make sure the application is built/run in debug mode. And in web.config, you can/should place the value as per my edit in the post - but that is a different question.  So, see my edit above.